# Running multiple crawlers in Scrapy sequentially

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I'm trying to figure out a way to run multiple Scrapy crawlers at the same time without running into memory issues etc.

At the moment, this is my run script:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy import log
from CSTest.spiders.CStest import MySpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


def setup_crawler(urls):
    spider = MySpider(urls=urls)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()

filename_ = raw_input("Enter filename of seed list: ") # Enter name of list of seed sites separated by newline
log.start()


with open(filename_, "r") as starturlfile:
    urls = [x.strip() for x in starturlfile.readlines()] # Put urls into a list

for domain in urls:
    setup_crawler([domain]) # Setup a crawler for each domain in seedlist




reactor.run() # Start reactor
```

This loads a list of seed sites and starts a crawler for  each site. This works fine, however if I had a seed list of 100+ sites, it would crash as it can't handle running 100+ crawlers at the same time.

To counter this, I would like to be able to run 10 crawlers at a time, sequentially going through the seed list until all the 100+ domains have been crawled.

I would need to somehow detect when a crawler has finished, so I can start another in it's place.

Is there a function to find out how many active crawlers there are? So I could just put a while loop like

```
while True:
    if active_crawler_number < 10:
        start_the_next_crawler()#
    time.sleep(60)
```

I'm aware I could do something like:

```
self.crawler.signals.connect(self.next_site, signal=spider_closed)
```

But with that, it pauses the program until the crawler is complete, so I'd only be able to start 1 crawler at a time, instead of 10.

I'm not really sure what is the best way to tackle this problem, so please if you have any idea which road I should take, submit your answer :)

If any more information is needed from me to be able to receive help, please just let me know I will edit my post and add it in.

Comment: Try using `threading` to create more than one process at a time.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using subprocess and spider arguments? In your example you are using a single process for all your spiders, which is a waste if you have a multi core cpu.

Subprocess also has a way to [determine when the process is done](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).

Another way of doing it is using [Scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd). The project is functional, but we are looking for new maintainers.

And the third way I can think of is using [Scrapy signals](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/signals.html), I think `engine_stopped` is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Because the subprocesses take up a lot of memory. We are using twisted. It should handle concurrent IO... that's it's whole purpose.

Comment: @Chris I have no idea what you are running inside your spiders. But a normal spider shouldn't take more than 100MB. Anyways here is a link to the updated documentation: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

Comment: Oh no, it's way under 100 MB... if it were 100 MB I'd be in serious trouble! It's still pretty bulky to spawn a subprocess for each scrape.